# wxWidgets keyboard event

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a problem with using Key event: 
there is example in documentation:

```
void OnChar(wxKeyEvent& event, double moveSpeed)
{
wxChar uc = event.GetUnicodeKey();
if ( uc != WXK_NONE )
{
    ...
}
else // No Unicode equivalent.
{
    // It's a special key, deal with all the known ones:
    switch ( event.GetKeyCode() )
    {
        case WXK_LEFT:
        case WXK_RIGHT:
            break;
        case WXK_F1:
            break;
    }
}
```

but what if i have to use keyboards event in different function ?
I know that in other library you can simply use:

```
if (keyDown(SDLK_DOWN))
{
    //code
}
```

but how can I use that in wxwidgets ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [wxGetKeyStats() function](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__funcmacro__misc.html#ga82a18ac43492bfb375604c41b71ce84f) if you really need to, but usually you definitely want to react to keyboard events instead of checking for the key state.

Comment: Thanks! wxGetKeyStats() was enough for me.